# How can I use gradle project in maven project as dependecy

Tags: java, maven, gradle

I have one Gradle module I need to use inside a Maven project as a dependency. Can you suggest to me how I can achieve this?

Comment: Add as dependency? How things are build (ant, maven, Gradle or whatever) doesn't matter. As long as that module is in a central repository you can just declare it as a dependency.

Comment: If it is an existing library go to mvnrepository and find that same dependency and select the appropiate syntax for maven

Comment: Don't mix gradle and maven in the same git project.